# Disable custom app settings

Tags: ios, swift, settings

I have an app where I'd like to open the `Settings.app` so the user can enable Wi-Fi or mobile data, but when I use

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

I get redirected to my custom settings, where I have an option for `Notifications` and one for `Use Mobile Data`.

Is there a way to either

1. Disable these custom settings, or
2. Show the main settings view, or
3. Another way to redirect the user to the Wi-Fi settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Apple, only allows you to open the settings app on with your now app settings selected.

As for you your apps settings you want to disable, this is also not possible since these are the defaults settings for each app.

Comment: Is this really the answer? Why would they not let you include the "default access settings" alongside your custom settings? But I can't find anything on this either.